# How to generate ArangoDB queries mechanically?

Tags: arangodb, aql

AQL seems to be well optimized for human use, but not so much for programmatic use.  Basically, I'd like to mechanically generate ArangoDB queries, based on an existing data structure (e.g., a tree of lists and maps). Alternatively, is there another query language I should consider?

I haven't actually tried anything yet.  Still exploring possibilities...